# Why rebind<U>::other are deprecated in C++17 and removed in C++20?

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20, allocator

I know that it deprecated and removed only in std::allocator. And I can implement it on my own allocators. But why it is deprecated?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`rebind` was a clunky, pre-C++11 way of taking an allocator type for `T` and converting it into an allocator type for `U`. I say "pre-C++11" because C++11 gave us a much more convenient way to do it: template aliases.

`allocator_traits` template has a member template alias `rebind<U>` that computes `Allocator<U>` for the allocator it is a trait for. It can use the `rebind` member of the allocator if it is available, otherwise, it just yields `Allocator<U>`.

`allocator_traits` effectively defines a lot of functionality that `std::allocator` used to provide. This made a lot of members of `std::allocator` redundant, so they have been deprecated and removed in favor of the `traits`-based defaults.

Comment: To emphasize: `allocator_traits` was introduced in C++11, and needs those new language features to work.